# Domain name redirect to Elastic IP address when typed in browser Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, domain-name, godaddy

I Pointed my Godaddy domain to Amazon Elastic IP Address in godaddy zone file (poitned @ to my elastic IP address) ,When I write domain name in browser ,it redirects to Elatic IP address ,how to correct so that it opens only domain name and not redirect to IP Address

Comment: That's almost certainly a misconfiguration on your own server.  Read the server logs. You should see where it is issuing a redirect.